# Filtering objects from parse.com based on date

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I a retriving data from parse using a PFQuery, like this

```
var downloadQuery = PFQuery(class: "MyDatabase") 

 downloadQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

//retriving data her
                }
```

But is there a way that I can filter out objects created more than a week ago, or something like that?

I have used `downloadQuery.whereKey("price", equalTo: "Free")` to filter out certain objects but I can't figure out how to filter out objects based on the dates when they were created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Parse's `greaterThan`, `lessThan`, `greaterThanOrEqualTo`, `lessThanOrEqualTo` with a date to filter your query.

Eg:

```
var downloadQuery = PFQuery(class: "MyDatabase") 
downloadQuery.whereKey("createdAt", lessThanOrEqualTo: lastWeek)
```

`lastWeek` is a date object which you can calculate using @yesthisisjoe's answer above. This will only fetch objects created within a week from the current day so no extra filtering will be required on your app side.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by using `downloadQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")` to sort the results by the date they were created.

Then you can do something like:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let lastWeek = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Week, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])

for object in objects {
    if object.createdAt!.timeIntervalSinceDate(lastWeek).isSignMinus {
        //it's older than a week, so stop iterating through objects
        break
    }
    //it's within the past week, do something with the object
}
```